# How to apply ColorFunction only to data visible within PlotRange?

Tags: plotting, color, visualization

The following:

```
data = Table[i, {i, -10, 10, 0.1}];
ListPlot[data,
   DataRange -> {-10, 10}, Joined -> True, 
   PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-5, 5}}, 
   ColorFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y}, 
     Blend[{{0., Red}, {.5, Blue}, {1., Green}}, x]]]
```

Produces:

[image: Output of the above code showing the undesired outcome.]

But I'd like to be able to apply the `ColorFunction` like this:

[image: This is the desired outcome.]

Which is produced by:

```
data = Table[i, {i, -5, 5, 0.1}];
ListPlot[data,
 DataRange -> {-5, 5}, Joined -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-5, 5}}, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y}, Blend[{{0., Red}, {.5, Blue}, {1., Green}}, x]]]
```

However, it is necessary that the `data` and `DataRange` not be changed, i.e., there should be some way to produce the outcome of the above code by using the initial code which was defined.

Even using `Plot`:

```
Plot[x, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-5, 5}}, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y}, Blend[{{0., Red}, {.5, Blue}, {1., Green}}, x]]]
```

Produces the same undesired outcome as in the first image. The same method for the initially defined code should work for this as well, wherein the `ColorFunction` is applied to only what is visible within the `PlotRange`. (Ergo, here it would be such that the `{x, -10, 10}` needs to remain unchanged.)

How can `ColorFunction` be applied only to what is visible within the `PlotRange`?

Comment: @C.E. Yes this would be correct to assume. The data range helps prevent `ListPlot` from just assigning the index as the x-coordinate, and it’s helpful that the user doesn’t need to do some transposition procedure to make the (x, y) pairs themselves (especially for a list of lines, as opposed to just one line as it is here). And the plot range then dictates what is visible of that data that’s been affected by the data range. The setting of the data range is necessary, and I’d think there should be some way to only apply `ColorFunction` to what is visible in the plot range.

Comment: If you cannot change the `PlotRange` or `DataRange`, rescale the `ColorFunction`, e,g., `ListPlot[data, DataRange -> {-10, 10}, Joined -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-5, 5}}, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y}, 
   Blend[{{0., Red}, {.5, Blue}, {1., Green}}, Rescale[x, {-5, 5}]]],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]`

Comment: @BobHanlon that’s a decent idea, but wouldn’t that would only work for this example, though? My visible x-range is (-10, 10), but only by chance is the visible part of the line ranging from (-5, 5). If I have a more complicated set of functions/data, I would have to manually set this for each line. Which, if it comes down to it, this is possible, but not as trivial as I hope it can be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `DataRange` and the `PlotRange` cannot be changed, then at the expense of plotting twice:

```
$Version

(* "12.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

data = Table[i, {i, -10, 10, 0.1}];

lp = ListPlot[data,
   DataRange -> {-10, 10},
   Joined -> True,
   PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-5, 5}}];
```

Determine the visible range of `x` in the plot

```
{xmin, xmax} = MinMax[Select[
    Cases[lp, {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}, Infinity],
    Element[#, Rectangle @@ Transpose[
        PlotRange /. Options[lp, PlotRange]]] &][[All, 1]]]

(* {-5, 5.} *)
```

Redraw the plot with a `ColorFunction` scaled to the visible range.

```
ListPlot[data,
 DataRange -> {-10, 10},
 Joined -> True,
 PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-5, 5}},
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y},
   Blend[{{0., Red}, {.5, Blue}, {1., Green}},
    Rescale[x, {xmin, xmax}]]],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Does this only work for a single line at a time?

Comment: I was able to finagle this to work for what I needed once I changed up the min/max of the visible range to work for a set of lines! I'll wait a bit to accept this in case anyone wants to put anything else down, but I think this worked well for what I needed :D Thanks Bob!

Comment: Hey Bob, can you show how one might do this for `Plot`? It seems it only works (without some necessary finagling) for `ListPlot`. When I use the `MinMax` code it likes to grab up some of the extra parts of the plotting (maybe related to using Frame?) and gives me an inaccurate Min/Max range. Though, the general concept helped me accomplish what I wanted!

Comment: @CATrevillian - if you are plotting `f[x]` use `{xmin, xmax} = #[{x, pltRng[[1, 1]] <= x <= pltRng[[1, 2]], pltRng[[2, 1]] <= f[x] <= pltRng[[2, 2]]}, x, Reals] & /@ {MinValue, MaxValue}`; or, if necessary, replace `{MinValue, MaxValue}` with `{NMinValue, NMaxValue}`.